# Optimal value in $\max_{x} \max_{y} f(x,y) = \max_{x,\ y} f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to understand a few things about sequential and simultaneous optimization in [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825166/sequential-maximization-max-x-max-y-fx-y-vs-simultaneous-maximization). In this post, it is shown that

$$\max_{x} \max_{y} f(x,y) = \max_{x,\ y} f(x,y).\tag{1}$$

Thanks to @Shiv Tavker comment, I understand that in order to get the optimal value $z^*=(x^*, y^*)$ in the RHS of $(1)$, we have to solve the system $\nabla_z f(z) = 0$ w.r.t. $z$, where $z = (x,y)$.

In addition, from the LHS of $(1)$ we have,
$${x^*}' = \arg \max_x f(x, y)\tag{2}$$ and $${y^*}' = \arg \max_y f({x^*}', y)\tag{3}.$$ Let ${z^*}' = ({x^*}', {y^*}')$.

As far as I understand, I think that given $(1)$, we can state that ${z^*}' \equiv {z^*}$. However, I am thinking if there are any cases that ${z^*}' \equiv {z^*}$ does not hold? Could you please someone give some comments or an answer of things are not so simple? Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT1:** Let $$\mathcal{f}(x, y) = -\frac{1}{2}\:\mathbf{z}^T \left(\mathbf{A} + \frac{xy}{2} \:\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{z} - \frac{y}{6} \lambda - \frac{y}{12}x^3,$$ where $x\geq 0$, $y,\lambda > 0$, $\mathbf{A}$ a real symmetric positive semmi-definite, and $\mathbf{z}$ are fixed.

**EDIT2:** Let $\mathbf{t}(x,y) = - (\mathbf{A} + 0.5 x y\: \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{z}$. If we first solve $\partial_x f(x,y) = 0$ we get $$x = \| \mathbf{t}(x,y)\|\tag{4},$$ for $y >0$. Then, if we solve $\partial_y f(x,y) = 0$ and use $(4)$ we get $$\sqrt[3]{\lambda} = \| \mathbf{t}(x,y)\|.\tag{5}$$

Next, suppose that we first solve $x = \| \mathbf{t}(x,y)\|$ w.r.t. $x$ to get an optimal ${x^*}'$ and then solve $\sqrt[3]{\lambda} = \| \mathbf{t}({x^*}', y)\|$ w.r.t. $y$ to get ${y^*}'$. Can we say that ${z^*}' \equiv {z^*}$?

Comment: What would $\max_y f(x,y)$ mean?

Comment: Yes, you can set the derivative to be zero for both of the variables simultaneously. Note that.. this is same as setting gradient, $\nabla f = 0$. However, beware you may end up in local optimas.

Comment: Do you mean: $${x^*}'(y) = \arg \max_x f(x, y)  \qquad (2)$$
$${y^*}' = \arg \max_y f({x^*}'(y), y) \qquad (3).$$
Let ${z^*}' = ({x^*}'({y^*}'), {y^*}')$.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks for the interest. Yes this is my case. The solution ${x^*}'$ depends on $y$.

Comment: @RiverLi actually my equation is

 $$\mathcal{f}(x, y) = -\frac{1}{2}\:\mathbf{z}^T \left(\mathbf{A} + \frac{xy}{2} \:\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{z} - \frac{y}{6} \lambda - \frac{y}{12}x^3,$$

where $\lambda$, $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{z}$ are fixed. I was hopping for a more general question that is why I didn't mention it in the main post. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @darkmoor I think you should go straight to the point (your $f(x, y)$) in the question.

Comment: @darkmoor Is $A$ real symmetric positive definite? Is $\lambda > 0$? Is the domain is $(0, \infty)^2$? Do you want to solve the optimization problem, or want to analyze if ${z^*}' \equiv {z^*}$ as you said in the question?

Comment: @RiverLi thanks again for the interest, I did some edits in my post. Generally I am trying to solve $\max_{x,y} \: f(x,y)$ by using $(1)$. That is by solving it sequentially which I fond more easy that solving it simultaneously which I found more difficult.  So at first place I am interested to know if ${z^*}' \equiv {z^*}$. In any case, I am very grateful for any additional information.

Comment: @RiverLi I add some more details in my post. I hope it is more clear now of what I am asking.

Comment: @podiki $\max_y f(x,y)$ is the maximum with respect to $y$ for a generic fixed $x$. It is therefore a function of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is positive definite then $A=X^TDX$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$. Hence $$z^T\left(A+\frac{xy}{2}I\right)^{-1}z=(Xz)^T\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1+\frac{xy}{2} & 0&\cdots&0 \\ 0 &\lambda_2+\frac{xy}{2}&\cdots&0 \\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0\\0&0&\cdots\lambda_n+\frac{xy}{2} \end{pmatrix}^{-1}(Xz)=\sum_{i=1}^nw_i^2\left(\lambda_i+\frac{xy}{2}\right)^{-1},$$ with $w=Xz$.

Otherwise, if you denote $$M=A+\frac{xy}{2}I,$$ you can see that $MM^{-1}=I$ and follows that
$$\frac{\partial\,M}{\partial\,x}M^{-1}+M\frac{\partial\,M^{-1}}{\partial\,x}=0.$$
You find that $$\frac{\partial\,M^{-1}}{\partial\,x}=-\frac{y}{2}\left(M^{-1}\right)^2.$$
Hence, if $$\frac{\partial\,f(x,y)}{\partial\,x}=\frac{y}{4}z^T\left(M^{-1}\right)^2z-\frac{y}{4}x^2=0.$$ The condition on $y>0$  gives you $$x^2=z^T\left(M^{-1}\right)^2z.$$

If you also have $$\frac{\partial\,f(x,y)}{\partial\,y}=\frac{x}{4}z^T\left(M^{-1}\right)^2z-\frac{\lambda}{6}-\frac{1}{12}x^3=0.$$

It follows that
$$\frac{x}{4}x^2-\frac{\lambda}{6}-\frac{1}{12}x^3=0.$$ And you have $x^*=\sqrt[3]{\lambda}$.

This helps you to handle with the equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$.

**Remark:**

1. Equation (2) probably  gives you implicit curves, say $X(x,y)=0$, hence your equation (3)  looks to becomes a constrained optimization problem, which can be harder to solve ([this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896584/system-of-equations-in-lagrange-multiplier-problem) can be useful). If this last problem has only one solution then this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825166/sequential-maximization-max-x-max-y-fx-y-vs-simultaneous-maximization) imply that it is the one you are looking for.
2. In a general case equations $\partial_x f(x,y) = 0$ and $\partial_y f(x,y) = 0$ probably  gives implicit curves to you, say $u(x,y)=0$ and $v(x,y)=0$. This gives you a system of equations, with two equations and two variables, that you can try to solve numerically, like with [Newton’s method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013195/why-is-newtons-method-faster-than-gradient-descent/4404742#4404742) or other that you can find on SearchOnMath.
3. The set of solutions of $X(x,y)=0$ is a subset of the set of solution of $u(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Could you please elaborate a little more on how this helps to handle the equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ for entire $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Indeed, I think that the equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ can be changed to a system of two equations, or two polynomial equations, in two variable. Probably you will need a numerical method to solve them.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed answer on the whole problem or elaborate on ${z^*}' \equiv {z^*}$?

Comment: I did some change in my answer. I am trying to find an example to clarify my point.

Comment: [This example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28x%2Cy%29%3D-%28x%5E%282%29%2By%5E%282%29-1%29%5E%282%29+%28x%5E%282%29%2Bxy-4%29%5E%282%29) is to  try to help.

Comment: In this example I want to show that $\min_xf(x,y)$ is a number, in this case is $0$. But the $\arg\min_xf(x,y)$ gives you the set $E$ containing both implicit curves $x^2+y^2-1=0$ and $x^2+xy-4=0$. On the other side, the equation $\partial_xf(x,y)=0$ has a bigger set of possible solution.

Comment: Why $X(x, y) = 0$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and not only a function of $y$ as the optimal $x^*$ is fixed? Also, why the aforementioned analysis helps to deal with the simultaneous optimization $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$? Last by not least, could you please elaborate a little more on the Remark 3.?

Comment: I understand that your equation (2) is in a general context. So the aforementioned example show you that $X(x,y)=0$ can gives you more that one implicit curve. And even one impicit curves can gives you more then one function, say $x(y)$. And, in general, $x^*$ is unknown at this point.

Comment: In general, the equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a way to find possible local minimizing points. It can gives you saddle point, local minimum or maximal points, for instance.

Comment: But, in your particular function given by EDIT1, equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ gives you only one $x=x^*=\sqrt[3]{\lambda}$. It remain to find possible values to $y$ in the equation $(\sqrt[3]{\lambda})^2=z^T\left((A+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\lambda}y}{2}I)^{-1}\right)^2z$ and test it to exclude possible non minimal points of $f(x,y)$. @darkmoor

Comment: So for some $\lambda$, we can compute $x=x^*=\sqrt[3]{\lambda}$ and then solve somehow the non-linear equation? Will we take the same solution if we have solved somehow $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. You can think about the hessian matrix to test local minimum points.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not catch your comment. Can you please be a little more precise on my two comment questions? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134931/discussion-between-jose-c-ferreira-and-darkmoor).